# IdentityServer4 client redirectURI issue

Tags: identityserver4

I have the following client configured on the IdentityServer4 host side:

```
new Client
{
     ClientId = "myClient",
     ....
     RedirectUris = {"https://localhost:44001/home/claims", 
                      "https://localhost:44001/"}
     ....
}
```

I am currently trying to get it to return in such a way that it works regardless of which controller in the client app it originates from (since redirectURI is configured at startup time on the client app & has to match the server's client config).

In the client app startup, the relevant code:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
     ...
     ClientId = "myClient",
     RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44001/",
     ...
}
```

When I set the redirectUri to the second option above, "https://localhost:44001" on the client startup, I get redirected to the client error controller with the following error:

> "Sorry, there was an error  : unauthorized_client    Invalid
>   redirect_uri".

In addition, the server outputs the following error to console:

> Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in
>   System.Private.CoreLib.dll
>   IdentityServer4.Validation.AuthorizeRequestValidator:Error: Invalid
>   redirect_uri: https://localhost:44001/ {   "ClientId": "myClient",
>   ...   "AllowedRedirectUris": [
>       "https://localhost:44001/home/claims",
>       "https://localhost:44001/"   ], "SubjectId": "anonymous",   "RequestedScopes": "",   "Raw": {
>       "client_id": "myClient",
>       "redirect_uri": "https://localhost:44001/",
>       "response_mode": "form_post",
>       "response_type": "code id_token",
>       ...   } }

It's almost like you cannot have multiple redirect URIs for a client, but that can't be right.

Comment: OK, after making the second redirectUri the only one, I still got the error.  I took off the trailing slash ('/') and it finally worked.  I'll have to work with this some more.  The error could have been more descriptive.

Comment: OK - if you just set the redirectUri the client's main URL, it'll go ultimately back to the controller that was authorized.  So after setting client and server configs of redirectUri for this client to "https://localhost:44001", I can now have multiple controllers with the [authorize] annotation and they'll work properly.